# Navigation bar collapsing when shrinking window

Tags: css, html, navigationbar

First off here is the code:

```
#menu {
    padding:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;



}


#menu li {
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border:1px solid black; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F2FF00, #AEFF00);
    margin-left:10px;
}



#menu a {
    display:block;
    padding:auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 10px;


    color: #0095FF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #0095FF;
}
```

The buttons moves down when I shrink the window. If can set the height to menu so it wont change, but  still the buttons go outside of the menu element, why does this happen?

Here is jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/nqdXc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a width of 100% on the menu, and float left on the li's, if the menu can not fit the li's they will drop down. This is expected behaviour.

I am not sure the effect you are trying to achieve, but you can set a minimum width on the menu like so:

```
#menu {
    min-width: 360px;
}
```

If you let us know what the desired effect is, we might be able to help you further

Comment: The desired effect is, that those buttons don't move down when you shrink the window.
That works, thanks :)

Comment: Isn't there any way to set the menu width to the width of the content? Because now I have to change the min-width if I put more stuff in the menu.

Comment: It would depend on your design. Basically if you do not set a width at all (or 100%) the browser will try to fit all content into the space it has available, therefore the elements will stack underneath each other as there is no room next to the previous ones. Most of the time for a page layout we know the desired width of a page and set a container element to be that width. There are standard widths, that are usually set to common screen sizes, for example even this stackoverflow page has a width of 980px set to is `#content` container.